# shell script about awk and ipcs

Tags: shell

after I type the command, ipcs -m | awk '{print $1, $2}'
I get below

------ Shared
key shmid
0x000186ad 11239433
0x000186ac 17694733
0x0000271c 4849681

I have a key 100012. It is equal to 0x186ac. How can I get the shmid=17694733 by using a shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
key=$1
ipcs -m | awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`ipcs -m | awk '{print strtonum($1),$2}' | awk '$1==10012{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing is probably:

```
ipcs -m | awk '$1 == 100012 { print $2 }'
```

Awk will do the hex conversion for you.

Comment: Then try `ipcs -m | awk 'strtonum($1)==100012 { print $2 }'`. This is definitely the more elegant answer; two Awks should rarely be necessary.